# MouseEnter / MouseOut events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseout

I've been reading articles online, watching YouTube videos - I am lost. This is the last bit of code I have tried, which as probably changed by now as you read this. It looks so simple, I don't understand what I am doing wrong? My mind just will not grasp this. Any help? I am trying to replace the image (src) with the image in (id) when the mouse is over it. Right now I am really just trying to get an alert when I mouse over the image. Anything!

**** UPDATED CODE ****

THIS JUST IN! I'm an idiot. Javascript file wasn't directed properly, missing the sub folder. Still struggling, but now at least my rollover is working. *palm to forehead*

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image Rollovers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<script src="js/rollover.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Rollover Test</h1>
    <ul id="rollover_test">
        <li>
            <img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="img1" id="images/h4.jpg" onmouseover="MouseOver('img1');" onmouseout="MouseOut('img1')">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="img2" id="images/h5.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="img3" id="images/h6.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>        
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Javascript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};

function MouseOver(id){ 
// I'm trying to figure out the syntax in here to swap the id and src tags
alert($("id").src);

};

function MouseOut(id){
alert("out");
}

window.onload = function () {
//preload images
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var i, link, image;
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links = links[i];
    image = new Image();
};
};
```

---

Comment: I think this link can help you: [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)

Comment: `$("li").on('mouseenter', function(){alert("yep"); });` - missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these simple three lines of code are enough to make it work.

```js
$("img").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Rollover Test</h1>
<ul id="rollover_test">
  <li>
    <img src="http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/stock-image/stock-image-15.jpg" alt="Img1" id="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/free-stock-nature-photos.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/free-stock-nature-photos.jpg" alt="Img2" id="http://www.jfcsmonmouth.org/Resources/Pictures/investing-in-stocks3---ticker-symbols_s600x600.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.jfcsmonmouth.org/Resources/Pictures/investing-in-stocks3---ticker-symbols_s600x600.jpg" alt="Img3" id="http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/stock-image/stock-image-15.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Thanasis - I've rejected your edit because the question's author tagged `jquery`, so there's no need to inform everybody that my solution requires it.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. However, perhaps the OP may not be able to make it work because he forgets to include the jQuery. That was my intention.

Comment: @Thanasis Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Yes - I didn't have that jquery script in there. I've been pondering this stupid thing for days and am determined to get it done tonight but I'm spent on it. I have to be missing something so simple. Anyway, adding that little thing did not make a difference.

Comment: @user3330694 What's the problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML the `id` attribute has been changed to `data-id` just because it's best to keep the `id` attribute for css identification.

by using mouseenter and mouseleave in cooperation the following snippet looks at each image as encountered and swaps its `src` attribute into a temporary `data-temp` attribute attached to that image.

Hopefully the snippet comments are self explanatory.

```js
$("li").find('img').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $this = $(this); // get the current img object
    var src = $this.attr('src'), // get the current src
      id = $this.attr('data-id'); //get the alternative src
    $this.data('temp', src); // store in a new temporary data attribute
    $this.attr('src', id);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    var temp = $(this).data('temp'); // lookup temp
    $(this).attr('src', temp); // swap image back
  }
})


/*

var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

function MouseRollover(img) {
  alert("made it");
  var oldIMG = $(this).attr("src");
  var newIMG = $(this).attr("id");
};

window.onload = function() {
    //preload images
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var i, link, image;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links = links[i];
      image = new Image();
    }
    //rollover
    $("li").on('mouseenter', function() {
          alert("yep");
        });
        
     }

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Rollover Test</h1>
<ul id="rollover_test">
  <li>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSm2etjS8VnJRwuZA8ormtAyPrIt8x0twLr-APiGwrkcX8NXe3P" alt="Img1" data-id="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-W40Oxb_QCTaGT9MVgTuXaDxacAKgChfvATaS9KffbHfGc16n">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTp6eZg_pJb0_NFxdaFYSnqMzPMJc-R_iwp2x8HarvdKzoNaCXv" alt="Img2" data-id="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSwvO67upMvk1q3MicNCujQ67D2EgJf8HyVA36FqM9qrv2B4Mue">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREN8xal0JlNdcPcz-94kQqZ8t3uBWEfm3T4LWpPY5PhX7qndGp" alt="Img3" data-id="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT07dVJl5ghqji58Su7Gs9RuSuCgleBDUITx2Dngh3ibVWzLfde">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

*** SOLVED ***

Once I figured out that my javascript wasn't linked right, it was just a matter of playing with syntax. Super easy. I am an idiot.

HTML

```
        <ul id="image_rollovers">
        <li>
            <img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="images/h4.jpg" id="img1" onmouseenter="MouseEnter('img1');" onmouseout="MouseOut('img1')">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="images/h5.jpg" id="img2" onmouseenter="MouseEnter('img2');" onmouseout="MouseOut('img2')">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="images/h6.jpg" id="img3" onmouseenter="MouseEnter('img3');" onmouseout="MouseOut('img3')">
        </li> 
    </ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};

function MouseEnter(id){
var img = $(id);
originalURL = img.src;
var newURL = img.alt;

img.src = newURL;
};

function MouseOut(id){
var img = $(id);

img.src = originalURL;
}

window.onload = function () {
var originalURL;
//preload images
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var i, link, image;
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links = links[i];
    image = new Image();
};
};
```

Works like a charm.

Thanks, all, for the tips and advice.

Comment: Would be nice if you would mark my answer as the best one, because it has lead you to solve your problem :)